# Does promotion occur before increment in Java?

Tags: java, pre-increment, type-promotion

I've seen this question in OCA questions and need to know why it outputs 90 and not 100. 
Here is the code:

```
int x = 9;
long y = x * (long) (++x);
System.out.println(y);
```

So, what I think this would do is, firstly, increment x (because that's what happens at first right?) and then it would do the type promotion and take left x which is 10, turn it into long and multiply those two longs. Right?

Comment: @Guy, he said what it prints, he wants to know why it prints what it does.

Comment: I know what is printed, but need an answer to why.

Comment: I'm not sure what the casting to long is contributing to this scenario. You get the same thing with `int y = x * (++x)`

Comment: @khelwood Next question could be "What if x = Integer.MAX_VALUE ?". But that's only speculation on my side.

Comment: @Fildor Wait what? No, dude. I asked this question because I thought it had something to do with type promotion. That's all.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything to do with type promotion.

Comment: No problem. It's from a textbook or something, right? @khelwood Hm, you're right ...

Comment: @Fildor Yeah, It's from some quiz app for Android tablet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The operands of each operator are evaluated from left to right. Therefore the first operand of the `*` operator, `x`, is evaluated before the second operand `(long) (++x)`. Therefore 9 is multiplied by 10.

Comment: An example of where precedence doesn't match order of evaluation. +1

Comment: @Eran, So basically, if Java sees variable in operation - it tries to get its values and write in operation right? from left to right. O.K. I understand now. Thank you Sir.